# Is there a setting somewhere that changes line spacing in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have two different machines with the same screen resolution but different amounts of space between the lines. I can only see 30 lines on one screen and 48 are visible on the other. I'm looking for a setting where I can decrease the spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second computer had a different Windows magnification percentage. I forgot that setting existed lol.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have [syntactic line compression](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/06/04/see-more-lines-of-code-with-syntactic-line-compression/) from Productivity Power Tools enabled on your second machine.

Comment: I just checked, doesn't look like I do. Thanks though!